# SFML Game Menu selection switch

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm creating a simple game using SFML. I've done a main menu with Play, Scores and Exit buttons.
I have a class `MainMenu` that creates the graphic part and handles the input from the keyboard.

```
void MainMenu::InputHandler(sf::RenderWindow & window)
{
    int selected= 0;
    std::cout << selected;
    sf::Event event;

while (window.pollEvent(event))
{
    switch (event.type)
    {

    case sf::Event::Closed:
        window.close();
        break;

    case sf::Event::KeyPressed:

        switch (event.key.code)
            {
                if (selected>= 0 && selected<= 3)
                {
                    case sf::Keyboard::S:
                        selected++;
                        std::cout << selected;
                        break;

                    case sf::Keyboard::W:
                        selected--;
                        std::cout << selected;
                        break;
                }
            }
        break;
    }
}
```

I call this method in my `gameLoop()` function in `Game.cpp` class.
My problem is that if I press 's' to scroll down the menu option to select option 1, the selected options comes back to option 0 straight away, as the ouptut to the console in the image below shows:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe because you have int selected= 0 when you call the input handler?

Comment: I have to initialize it, that's why I put selected = 0

Comment: Ok, and where is indexSelection assigned?

Comment: That was a typo, sorry. Edited now

Comment: But again, what do you expect when you write `int selected= 0;
    std::cout << selected;`?

Comment: Of course I expect 0, but if I press 'S' should change to 1. It does, but it doesn't stay on 1 and goes back to 0.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154261/discussion-between-martin-sand-and-koosshh56).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed you ned to move `int selected=0;` into the class constructor and move the MainMenu object initialization out of the game loop.

Also the if statement inside the switch statement will never be reached. It is better to write something like this:

```
switch (event.type){
    case sf::Event::Closed:
        window.close();
        break;

    case sf::Event::KeyPressed:
        switch (event.key.code){
          case sf::Keyboard::S:
            if (selected<3) selected++;
            std::cout << selected;
            break;

          case sf::Keyboard::W:
            if (selected>0) selected--;
            std::cout << selected;
            break;
          }
        break;
      }
    }
```